# How to do periodic / scheduled actions using Flutter Redux?

Tags: redux, dart, flutter, redux-thunk, flutter-redux

I'm building a mobile app using Flutter, in which I use [flutter_redux](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux) and [redux_thunk](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/redux_thunk).
There's two kind of timed actions I want to achieve:

1. Dispatch certain action every N seconds (repeated)
2. Dispatch an action once after N seconds, likely from a thunk action (single run)

Are there any packages that wrap this logic?
What would be your suggested way to achieve the two kind of scheduled actions?

Comment: Why not do `Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: N), () => store.dispatch(action))`?  For the non-periodic case, you could use a non-periodic `Timer` or `Future.delayed`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't see a reason not to do it that way, I was just not sure if there would be other (perhaps better) ways to do it. If you can add it as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything special that you'd need to do specifically for Flutter Redux.  In Dart, the general way to do periodic operations would be to use [`Timer.periodic`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html):

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: N), () => store.dispatch(action));
```

For non-periodic operations, you could use a non-periodic [`Timer`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-async/Timer/Timer.html) or use [`Future.delayed`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html). (`Timer` gives you the ability to easily cancel it, but `Future` gives you a more direct way for the caller to specify how exceptions are handled.)